# How to assign event in event listener for Keyboard enter?

Tags: jquery

I have to perform some actions when a user presses <kbd>enter</kbd> on a selected `<li>`. Currently I am performing on click event as:

```
liList[i].addEventListener("Click",getText,false);
```

I am calling the function `getText` on `click` event. Now I want to add keyboard enter event as well. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The code you have is native JS, however you've tagged your answer as jQuery, so I'll answer as such:

```
$(liList[i]).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) { // 13 = enter key code
        getText(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(liList[i]).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 13) return; // 13 is the enter key code
    getText(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside the `getText` function:

```
function getText(e){
   var e = e || window.event
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

   if (code === 13) {  // enter key pressed    
        // your code
   }
}
```